# Updating mulitple lines of file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing automation script in python to update certain version in a file.
Here is the snippet from that file.

```
if "$(CURTARGET)" == "linux_rh_el6_x86_64_32"
        /* See $VOB/FMSrules.mk */
        GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER=4.4.7
        GOLDEN_CPPBKW_VER=3.4.6
        GOLDEN_LIBHDR_VER=$(GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER)
        RHEL_KERNEL=2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64
    end
    if "$(CURTARGET)" == "linux_rh_el7_x86_64_32"
        /* See $VOB/FMSrules.mk */
        GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER=4.8.5
        GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER=4.4.7
        GOLDEN_LIBHDR_VER=$(GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER)
        RHEL_KERNEL=3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64
    end
```

I have to update GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER,GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER & RHEL_KERNEL based on the value of $(CURTARGET).

AS you can see the 3 variables GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER,GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER & RHEL_KERNEL are not unique and i cannot directly search and update the same.

I tried coding it in this way.

```
def update_fmsrules():

    print " \n\n--- Updating FMSrules.mk ----\n"
    f = open(FMSrules_file,'r')
    lines = []
    while True:
        try:
            line= f.readline()
            #print line
            if (re.search(r'\blinux_rh_el7_x86_64_32\b',line)):
                print "matched\n"
                nextline = f.next()
                print nextline
                if "GOLDEN_CPPHDR_VER" in nextline:
                    print "entered if"
                    print line +"\ntrue\n"+ nextline
                    print f.tell()
                    break

        except StopIteration:
                    print "exception"
            return


    f.close()
```

But it is not working as expected.

```
print "matched\n"
```

I am seeing the above output.

```
nextline = f.next()
print nextline
```

But above line is not printing actual nextline but some garbage lines.
And the code is running infinitely.

what is the best way of doing this using python?

How can i do it using file operation in python?

Comment: Please create some pairs of sample input and desired output.

Comment: "based on the type of $(CURTARGET)" shouldn't that be "based on the value of $(CURTARGET)" ?

Comment: Are you referring to something called "ceratin" and its versions? Or is it a typo and should be "certain"?

Comment: Is the shown code your attempt to code? Or is it an example of an input file?

Comment: thats file content which needs to be updated & not the code.. i need the logic how it can be done using python